# General way to switch between Sqlite or SqlServer in EF Core?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, system.data.sqlite

I want to be able to switch on the fly between using SQLite and SqlServer as a db provider for Entity Framework in an ASP.NET Core app.

The usual pattern to associate a `DbContext` with a Database Provider is via code in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
        services.AddDbContext<FeedbackDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Feedback")));
```

Each of the database providers for EF Core adds its own extension method as `Use<Provider>`.

It is surprising to me that I can't find a way to specify the database provider for a connection string in config

Answer (score 4):

Very nice article that shows how do have two contexts, one per DbProvider, and to be able to also generate different migrations:

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/01/03/aspnet-core-ef-core-migrations-for-multiple-databases-sqlite-and-sql-server

Comment: Grazie. I don't usually upvote link only answers, but that article was quite helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to code changes only, you should modify context configuration. After installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` NuGet package, you should be able to just change:

from:

```
services.AddDbContext<FeedbackDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Feedback")));
```

to:

```
services.AddDbContext<FeedbackDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Feedback")));
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the "on the fly" nature of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same connection you can change the database name. I assume you will need to close, change then re-open. I've not tried this myself.

```
this.Database.GetDbConnection().ChangeDatabase("DB name");
```

Otherwise you can change the connection string to be used.

```
this.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString = "new connection string";
```

I use a separate partial file to hold any of my own code to prevent overwriting by the system on any database rebuilds. You can add a method or property to change the current connection string. Again, you may need to close, change, and re-open

```
public partial class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    void SetConnection(string s)
```